# How does clipping work in three.js frustum?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm learning three.js's frustum by modifying the example in [Scene Graph](https://threejs.org/manual/#en/scenegraph) below.

```js
function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 40;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 1000;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 50, 0);
  camera.up.set(0, 0, 1);
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 3;
    const light = new THREE.PointLight(color, intensity);
    scene.add(light);
  }

  // an array of objects who's rotation to update
  const objects = [];

  const radius = 1;
  const widthSegments = 6;
  const heightSegments = 6;
  const sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(
      radius, widthSegments, heightSegments);

  const sunMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({emissive: 0xFFFF00});
  const sunMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sunMaterial);
  sunMesh.scale.set(5, 5, 5);
  scene.add(sunMesh);
  objects.push(sunMesh);

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    objects.forEach((obj) => {
      obj.rotation.y = time;
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.144.0/three.min.js"></script>
```

Settings:

- A sphere at the origin with `radius = 1`.
- A camera positioned at `y = 50`, looking towards the origin, with the UP direction as `(0,0,1)`.
- Its frustum has `fov = 40`, `aspect = 2`, `near = 0.1` and `far = 1000`.

I changed two parameters:

- `near`: `0.1 → 48`
- `far`: `1000 → 52`.

I'm expecting the sphere being contained inside the frustum, but **why is the sphere's top part truncated**?

[image: sphere in frustum]

```js
function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 40;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 48;
  const far = 52;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 50, 0);
  camera.up.set(0, 0, 1);
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 3;
    const light = new THREE.PointLight(color, intensity);
    scene.add(light);
  }

  // an array of objects who's rotation to update
  const objects = [];

  const radius = 1;
  const widthSegments = 6;
  const heightSegments = 6;
  const sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(
      radius, widthSegments, heightSegments);

  const sunMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({emissive: 0xFFFF00});
  const sunMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sunMaterial);
  sunMesh.scale.set(5, 5, 5);
  scene.add(sunMesh);
  objects.push(sunMesh);

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    objects.forEach((obj) => {
      obj.rotation.y = time;
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.144.0/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Does setting `const widthSegments = 16; const heightSegments = 16;` solve your problem? Also try `sunMesh.scale.set( 25, 25, 25 );`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response.  The first two parameters control the number of points in the mesh instead of its diameter.  I've checked the last one.  That has cleared my doubts.  I've written an answer based on that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to WestLangley's comment, I've found out the answer: the property [`Object3D.scale`](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.scale) is a 3D vector that scales the object locally.  `Mesh` is  a subclass of `Object3D`.  In my modified example above, the "sphere" (a hexagon in fact) is scaled to 5×.  I commented out this line, so that there's no scaling (default factor 1×), and I observed that the "sphere" is contained inside the frustum.

```js
function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 10;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 49;
  const far = 51;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 50, 0);
  camera.up.set(0, 0, 1);
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 3;
    const light = new THREE.PointLight(color, intensity);
    scene.add(light);
  }

  // an array of objects who's rotation to update
  const objects = [];

  const radius = 1;
  const widthSegments = 6;
  const heightSegments = 6;
  const sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(
      radius, widthSegments, heightSegments);

  const sunMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({emissive: 0xFFFF00});
  const sunMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sunMaterial);
  //sunMesh.scale.set(5, 5, 5);
  scene.add(sunMesh);
  objects.push(sunMesh);

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    objects.forEach((obj) => {
      obj.rotation.y = time;
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.144.0/three.min.js"></script>
```

To check my understanding, I reduced the distance between `near` and the center of the "sphere" by `0.3`, and I observed a hole as expected.

```js
function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 10;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 49.3;
  const far = 50.7;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.set(0, 50, 0);
  camera.up.set(0, 0, 1);
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 3;
    const light = new THREE.PointLight(color, intensity);
    scene.add(light);
  }

  // an array of objects who's rotation to update
  const objects = [];

  const radius = 1;
  const widthSegments = 6;
  const heightSegments = 6;
  const sphereGeometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(
      radius, widthSegments, heightSegments);

  const sunMaterial = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({emissive: 0xFFFF00});
  const sunMesh = new THREE.Mesh(sphereGeometry, sunMaterial);
  //sunMesh.scale.set(5, 5, 5);
  scene.add(sunMesh);
  objects.push(sunMesh);

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    objects.forEach((obj) => {
      obj.rotation.y = time;
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}

main();
```

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}
#c {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/0.144.0/three.min.js"></script>
```

Remark: I'm answering my own question in order to clear it from the unanswered queue.